# Does the size of the 'bounding box' for the training data matter when transfer learning a SSD model with the Tensorflow object detection library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to transfer learn a mobilenet_v2_coco model on the publicly available GTSRB (German Traffic Signs) Dataset. 
I selected 3 classes to have a faster training time and I've already trained for about 10 000 epochs. Usually I already get decent results at this point in time. But my SSD fails to find anything on a livestream video I access over a small python program with my webcam. It even classifies almost the entire screen as one of the classes provided (the one that has more training data) with >90% confidence.

My guesses are that either this is because of the unbalanced data set (class1 = 2000 images, class2 = 1000 images, class3 = 800) or because of the images being filled with the object, without much noise or anything. So basically the ROI is almost as big as the dataset images, but the classifier aims to predict dash cam like videos, where the signs are usually very small.
Or do I just have to train harder and longer this time to get decent results?

The second part of my question is, if there is like a rule of thumb what the images in the dataset need to fulfil to output good predictions.

Comment: If I remember correctly, GTSRB is used to train object classification, while the COCO dataset is used to train object detection. CNN architectures like VGG-16 should be enough for you to perform the task you described. And lastly, try to balance your dataset.

Comment: @stormzhou but why are they providing bounding boxes then? and shouldn't I still be able to train an object detection model with them?